# How do I connect a router on one LAN port to another router on another LAN port on the same switch?

Tags: routing, router, switch

I have the following setup:

[image]

For non-technical reasons, I am unable to change the physical setup of the devices. What I'd like to do is have router 2 (a wireless router) act as a wireless AP that will forward clients to router 1. However, I have to do it through a switch (actually a router configured to be a switch). Is there any way to do this? Router 1 is set up with internet access and has a DHCP server up and running.

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tried VLANs ?

Comment: None of the 3 routers support VLANs (these are consumer-grade routers). The problem is that I don't even know where to begin. If router 2 was plugged into router 1, then it's not a problem, but I don't know what I should do when both are behind a switch.

Comment: Presumably R2 is acting as a DHCP server? in which case set the scope/s to use R1 as their DG - I don't see the issue here - you do know this site isn't for beginners right - it's for professional sysadmins

Answer (score 8):

Without further details it's difficult to give an appropriate answer.

In the simplest case, with everything on the same IP subnet (including router2's clients), same VLAN, dynamic IP attribution, etc., i.e. the routers can communicate directly without any special switching/routing configuration, all you need is cabling and:

- set router1 as default gateway on router2's clients (either statically or via DHCP)
- make sure that only router1 is providing DHCP leases on that network
- router2 should behave as a "dumb switch"

This way it should work, when a client plugged into router2 requests an IP address, the request is propagated through the network, and gets answered by router1 with the DHCP configuration parameters, including router1's IP address for default gw. The client picks it up and sets the routing table accordingly, should work from then on.

I have found this setup to work fine with consumer-grade wifi routers, even if they don't support "AP mode". When adding a new router, disabling DHCP on it and plugging one of the LAN ports into a network with a DHCP server will work and wifi (and wired) clients will get proper connectivity.

Comment: A better answer than the question deserves - well done you.